# What clr.ImportExtensions exactly does?

Tags: c#, python, .net, extension-methods, ironpython

I do not manage to find this on the internet.

Why use

```
clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq) ?
```

Why doesn't just

```
from System.Linq import *
```

do the work?

Is it because clr.ImportExtensions is the only way for IronPython to know what to do with an extension method?

Thank you